# FCM notification sometime got high delay (Server environment)

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using firebase-admin SDK to run the push code in the server environment. The code has been run in a Singapore server for quite a while but sometimes I found the delay is very high(around 15 seconds).

It happens almost every day but not in high frequency（5 times at most）. I am currently using

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendAll()
```

to send high-priority notification for both single and batch push to Android devices. Is there anything I can do to improve the performance?